# Can not connect to JupyterHub(using Python 3) - Errormessage: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, jupyter

### Unable to connect to JupyterHub after installation

I just installed JupyterHub and a new installation on pip3. My OS is MacOS Sierra. It seems a bit weird that it tried to connect to Malins-Macbook-Air. When I type $HOSTNAME in the terminal I get an empty string out, while when I type hostname it gives me Malins-Macbook-Air.local.

When I try to connect to jupyterHub, I get the following error:

```
⋊> ~/S/I/inf5860_oblig1 on master ⨯ jupyterhub                                                                                                                     17:44:39
[I 2018-02-01 17:44:42.484 JupyterHub app:834] Loading cookie_secret from /Users/malinaandahl/Skole/INF5860/inf5860_oblig1/jupyterhub_cookie_secret
[W 2018-02-01 17:44:42.518 JupyterHub app:955] No admin users, admin interface will be unavailable.
[W 2018-02-01 17:44:42.519 JupyterHub app:956] Add any administrative users to `c.Authenticator.admin_users` in config.
[I 2018-02-01 17:44:42.519 JupyterHub app:983] Not using whitelist. Any authenticated user will be allowed.
[I 2018-02-01 17:44:42.566 JupyterHub app:1528] Hub API listening on http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/
[W 2018-02-01 17:44:42.568 JupyterHub proxy:415]
    Generating CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN. Restarting the Hub will require restarting the proxy.
    Set CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN env or JupyterHub.proxy_auth_token config to avoid this message.

[W 2018-02-01 17:44:42.569 JupyterHub proxy:456] Running JupyterHub without SSL.  I hope there is SSL termination happening somewhere else...
[I 2018-02-01 17:44:42.569 JupyterHub proxy:458] Starting proxy @ http://*:8000/
17:44:42.771 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxying http://*:8000 to (no default)
17:44:42.779 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxy API at http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/routes
[E 2018-02-01 17:44:47.582 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to Malins-MacBook-Air.local:8000 [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[E 2018-02-01 17:44:52.590 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to Malins-MacBook-Air.local:8000 [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[E 2018-02-01 17:44:57.597 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to Malins-MacBook-Air.local:8000 [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[E 2018-02-01 17:45:02.605 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to Malins-MacBook-Air.local:8000 [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[E 2018-02-01 17:45:07.619 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to Malins-MacBook-Air.local:8000 [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[E 2018-02-01 17:45:12.634 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to Malins-MacBook-Air.local:8000 [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[E 2018-02-01 17:45:17.644 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to Malins-MacBook-Air.local:8000 [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[E 2018-02-01 17:45:22.652 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to Malins-MacBook-Air.local:8000 [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[E 2018-02-01 17:45:27.659 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to Malins-MacBook-Air.local:8000 [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[E 2018-02-01 17:45:32.668 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to Malins-MacBook-Air.local:8000 [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[E 2018-02-01 17:45:37.676 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to Malins-MacBook-Air.local:8000 [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[C 2018-02-01 17:45:37.677 JupyterHub app:1535] Failed to start proxy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 1533, in start
        yield self.proxy.start()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/proxy.py", line 489, in start
        yield server.wait_up(1)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/utils.py", line 146, in wait_for_server
        timeout=timeout
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/utils.py", line 135, in exponential_backoff
        raise TimeoutError(fail_message)
    TimeoutError: Server at Malins-MacBook-Air.local:8000 didn't respond in 1 seconds
```

I tried to run sudo jupyterhub, which gave me the same error message. The output for jupyter troubleshoot:

```
$PATH:
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/bin
    /bin
    /usr/sbin
    /sbin
    /opt/X11/bin
    /usr/local/git/bin
    /Library/TeX/texbin

sys.path:
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6
    /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

sys.executable:
    /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6

sys.version:
    3.6.4 (default, Jan  6 2018, 11:51:15)
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)]

platform.platform():
    Darwin-16.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit

which -a jupyter:
    /usr/local/bin/jupyter
    /usr/local/bin/jupyter

pip list:
    alembic (0.9.7)
    appnope (0.1.0)
    bleach (2.1.2)
    certifi (2018.1.18)
    chardet (3.0.4)
    decorator (4.2.1)
    entrypoints (0.2.3)
    html5lib (1.0.1)
    idna (2.6)
    ipykernel (4.8.0)
    ipython (6.2.1)
    ipython-genutils (0.2.0)
    jedi (0.11.1)
    Jinja2 (2.10)
    jsonschema (2.6.0)
    jupyter-client (5.2.2)
    jupyter-core (4.4.0)
    jupyterhub (0.8.1)
    Mako (1.0.7)
    MarkupSafe (1.0)
    mistune (0.8.3)
    nbconvert (5.3.1)
    nbformat (4.4.0)
    notebook (5.4.0)
    pamela (0.3.0)
    pandocfilters (1.4.2)
    parso (0.1.1)
    pexpect (4.3.1)
    pickleshare (0.7.4)
    pip (9.0.1)
    prompt-toolkit (1.0.15)
    ptyprocess (0.5.2)
    Pygments (2.2.0)
    python-dateutil (2.6.1)
    python-editor (1.0.3)
    python-oauth2 (1.0.1)
    pyzmq (16.0.4)
    requests (2.18.4)
    Send2Trash (1.4.2)
    setuptools (38.4.0)
    simplegeneric (0.8.1)
    six (1.11.0)
    SQLAlchemy (1.2.2)
    terminado (0.8.1)
    testpath (0.3.1)
    tornado (4.5.3)
    traitlets (4.3.2)
    urllib3 (1.22)
    wcwidth (0.1.7)
    webencodings (0.5.1)
    wheel (0.30.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is being posted here, in case anyone has the same issue: https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/1586

Answer (score 0):

for my error:

```
Unexpected error connecting to d7f9ec442130:8123 [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I edit file `/etc/hosts` and add a new line `d7f9ec442130 127.0.0.1`

It worked for me.

ref. to : https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/1586#issuecomment-469318376